# Skip unit-test if the user is not allowed to do it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, automated-tests

We are building our unit-tests with Visual Studio 10 integrated MS unit-tests.

Some functions in our application do only work right, if the user that tries to access this function has the right privileges - like being administrator of the computer (or even evaluated administrator (depending on the target system). For example, we are creating new performance counters - for that you do need to be administrator.

Now, I want to test those functions with unit tests. When I start VS as administrator, all is good. But we are also have an automated build system (Jenkins) that runs the unit tests with a normal user.
The question is, is there a nice way (like a method attribute) to skip tests when the user that runs the unit tests does not have the privileges to run them.

**EDIT 1**

Changing configurations based on target machines does not really satisfy me. I just found the [TestClassExtensionAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testclassextensionattribute.aspx) and some nice [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-1.aspx) how to implement it. I will try to go that way now, since it is much easier when developing tests.

Comment: Such tests are not really "unit tests", but rather "integration tests". The question remains valid though.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of a way.  A work around could be to use the TestCategory attribute to filter tests that you don't want your build to run.  If you google TestCategory attribute then you should find all the info you need on the MSDN.

Answer (score 5):

You could use TestCategories on your test.
Just mark your test with:

```
[TestCategory("Admin") TestMethod()]
public Void DebitTest()
{
}
```

And then exclude category:

```
mstest /testcontainer:MyTestprojectName.dll /category:"!Admin"
```

You can use multiple categories on each test

See more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But i do not want to fiddle with configurations, and will try another approach first.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put all relevant tests in a Test list and then just run this list, like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182461(v=vs.80).aspx